# СSS. Контейнер с margin: 0 auto

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Есть контейнер с `margin: 0` auto. Внутри есть другой контейнер. Можно ли отменить во внутреннем `margin:auto`, сделать на 100 процентов по ширине? Или надо выносить вне?

Comment: eicto - да, так, подходит.

Comment: Нет, не подходит:) Отступы же сверху могут быть.

Comment: и в чем проблема ? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/mNWjQ/5/

Comment: отчего там 50%? Если там сверху другие контейнеры, как мне определить топ?

Answer (score 1):

Во внутреннем контейнере переопределите `margin`.
К примеру:

```
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
```

Comment: вы меня неправильно поняли, мне надо чтобы внутренний контейнер был на всю ширину, а не внутри внешнего.

Answer (score 0):

Эх демоны вы)

Внутреннему блоку даете 5 следующих свойств

> ```
> #id_block {position:absolute;
> top:0;
> left:0;
> width:100%;
> height:100%}
> ```

Comment: мне топ 0 не подходит потому что блок может быть не на самом верху.

Answer (score -1):

можно http://jsfiddle.net/EHVEg/

там изза бордеров немного полезло, но это не важно. я бордеры для наглядности поставил

Comment: вы меня неправильно поняли, мне надо чтобы внутренний контейнер был на всю ширину, а не внутри внешнего.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, ну так чего мы тут угадываем?? выложите сюда http://jsfiddle.net/ пример вашего кода, а мы поправим

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mNWjQ/1/   

надо чтобы .inner был внутри .m-auto , отменить центрирование по горизонтали. Как в примере тут.

Comment: то есть вам нужно чтобы блок inner был в середине .m-auto, но помещать его внутрь .m-auto не нужно? правильно?

Comment: inner должен быть внутри .m-auto а выглядеть все должно быть как в моем примере.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, ну тогда как то так http://jsfiddle.net/mNWjQ/2/

Comment: как бэ , не похоже.

Comment: так что ли ? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/mNWjQ/3/

Comment: @eicto, автор наверное сам не знает чего хочет